# R callback functions using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I hope to use *mapPartitions* and *reduce* function of Spark (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html), using *sparklyr*.

It is easy in *pyspark*, the only thing I need to use is a plain python code. I can simply add python functions as callback function. So easy.

For example, in *pyspark*, I can use those two functions as follows:

```
mapdata = self.rdd.mapPartitions(mycbfunc1(myparam1))
res = mapdata.reduce(mycbfunc2(myparam2))
```

However, it seems this is not possible in R, for example *sparklyr* library. I checked RSpark, but it seems it is another way of query/wrangling data in R, nothing else.

I would appreciate if someone let me know how to use those two functions in R, with R callback functions.

Comment: You're correct that this has not yet been implemented within `sparklyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SparkR` you could use internal functions - hence the prefix `SparkR:::` - to accomplish the same.

```
newRdd = SparkR:::toRDD(self)                  
mapdata = SparkR:::mapPartitions(newRdd, function(x) { mycbfunc1(x, myparam1)})
res = SparkR:::reduce(mapdata, function(x) { mycbfunc2(x, myparam2)})
```

I believe `sparklyr` interfaces only with the `DataFrame` / `DataSet` API.

Comment: Yes, this answer is the most promising, but I saw an error occured from this. Which says "not exported function".

> toRDD
Error: object 'toRDD' not found
> SparkR::toRDD
Error: 'toRDD' is not an exported object from 'namespace:SparkR'

sparkR --version version 2.0.0

Here is an example.
http://pastebin.com/i2GLVctt

Comment: try `SparkR:::toRDD(self)`, note the triple colon.

Comment: Oh, I see. This approach uses internal function on purpose :)

Comment: @Kim Please read the JIRA which removed this API before using this. It is internal because it is not stable enough and there are many known bugs.